# Есть ли возможность отключить assert?

Tags: python

Собственно и весь вопрос в заголовке.

Если такой возможности нет, то не пойму, в чем ценность такой инструкции как `assert` вообще?

А то как-то все неубедительно. Ведь можно простыми `if ...: print()` в одну строку обойтись...
P.S: я уже получил ответ от `andreymal`, однако интересно отключить `assert` первой строчкой в коде... возможно ли это? Ведь os.environ читается до первой строчки модуля...

Comment: Вообще лично для меня `assert`ы полезны тем, что они явно демонстрируют читателю кода, что определённые условия в программе в принципе невозможны (или по крайней мере задумывались невозможными). Если переписать `assert` как `if`, то тот, кто читает код, может решить, что нарушение условия является нормальной ситуацией в программе, а `assert`ы предназначены для ловли именно ненормальных и невозможных ситуаций — багов. И мне плевать, можно ли отключать `assert`ы или нет — для меня это в первую очередь способ организации порядка в коде и упрощения его чтения и отладки.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273211/disable-assertions-in-python

Comment: «отключить assert первой строчкой в коде» — а вот это уже вряд ли

Comment: Алсо, менять суть вопроса уже после того, как дан ответ, не очень хорошо

Comment: так а смысл отключать снаружи? суть вопроса не поменялась. Скорее - конкретизировалась.

Comment: Так а смысл отключать внутри? Хотите отладку — запускаете как обычно. Хотите без отладки — запускаете `python -O`. Всё. Какую задачу вы хотите решить своим странным отключением?

Comment: отключить отладку при передаче пользователю

Comment: Пусть пользователь отключает через `python -O`, очевидно же :) Не менее очевидно, что конкретный способ отключения зависит от способа передачи программы пользователю (а их много), который вы не потрудились указать

Comment: Вообще, скорее всего включение-отлключение отладки определяется задолго до запуска каких-либо модулей вообще. При компиляции кода `assert` и `__debug__` вырезаются из байткода (при включенной отладке заменяются на эквивалентные выражения, при отключенной убираются совсем) (поправьте меня если не прав), и включать-выключать отладку уже во время работы программы становится технически невозможно. Поэтому единственное, что вам остаётся — как-то адаптировать один из перечисленных в ответе способов для вашей ситуации.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`assert`, в отличие от `if`, предназначен для обнаружения ситуаций, которые задумывались как в принципе невозможные в программе: для поиска багов. Отключать `assert` обычно не стоит, но для ускорения программы это иногда может быть полезным.

Для его отключения есть несколько способов.

### Для отдельного Python-процесса

Использование флага `-O` (большая латинская O) включает базовую оптимизацию и отключает все `assert`ы в данном процессе.

Пример:

```
$ python -Oc "assert False"

$ python -c "assert False"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

### Для окружения

Можно использовать переменную окружения для установки этого флага. Тогда он будет применён ко всем процессам, использующим данное окружение.

Например, установка и очистка переменной окружения в Windows:

```
C:\>python -c "assert False"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
C:\>SET PYTHONOPTIMIZE=TRUE

C:\>python -c "assert False"

C:\>SET PYTHONOPTIMIZE=

C:\>python -c "assert False"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

### Для конкретного места в коде

Когда выражение, прописанное в `assert`, ложно, выбрасывается исключение `AssertionError`. Если ожидается, что такой-то `assert` провалится, можно просто перехватить это исключение:

```
>>> try:
...     assert False, "мы знаем, что это упадёт"
... except AssertionError as e:
...     print(repr(e))
...
AssertionError('мы знаем, что это упадёт',)
```

После такого перехвата исключения, если вы не выбросите новое исключение, программа продолжит выполняться дальше.

*(Впрочем, так делать плохо: если `assert` провалился, нужно принять все меры по исправлению программы так, чтобы он больше не проваливался, а не скрывать возможный баг таким костылём.)*

### Дополнительная информация

Из [документации `assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement):

Выражение с `assert`, вроде такого:

```
assert expression #, optional_message
```

Эквивалентно такому коду:

```
if __debug__:
    if not expression: raise AssertionError #(optional_message)
```

И

> встроенная переменная `__debug__` имеет значение `True` в обычных условиях и `False`, если включены оптимизации (аргумент командной строки `-O`).

Из документации по использованию `python`:

> [**-O**](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-o)
>
> Включает базовые оптимизации. См. также `PYTHONOPTIMIZE`.

и

> [**PYTHONOPTIMIZE**](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE)
>
> Если эта переменная является непустой строкой, это аналогично использованию опции `-O`.
>   Если в переменной указано целое число, это аналогично добавлению опции `-O` несколько раз.

---

<sup>Слегка вольный перевод [ответа от Aaron Hall на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668496)</sup>

Comment: except AssertionError выглядит как anti-pattern. assert указывает на баг в коде (никакой ввод: ни правильный ни ошибочный не должен к AssertionError приводить) Какой use-case вы представляете, в котором это полезно?

Comment: @jfs костыль для обхода проблемы в сторонней библиотеке?)) А вообще это перевод и не я придумал AssertionError перехватывать, будет лучше задать этот вопрос автору оригинала на enSO (но ответ дополнил)

Comment: Слепо не стоит копировать ответы. В сторону: автор оригинала удаляет комментарии к своим ответам, не адресуя (по мнению автора комментария) проблемы, отмеченные в комментарии.